# Python mutiply pandas dataframe containing scientific and float values with a float

Tags: python, dataframe, scientific-notation

```py
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.DataFrame({‘years’:[‘Y0’,‘Y1’,’Y2’,’Y3’],‘price1’:[0.01, 0.0029,0.00368,0.00439536],
‘price2’:[0.02, 0.001, 9.161781253394068e-04,0.001718]})

df.iloc[1:,1:] = df.iloc[1:,1:].mul(0.75)
```

It’s getting error due to scientific values in df, please let me know if any one has any suggestions or help to fix this?

Error:

```
TypeError: Could not operate 0.75 with block values can’t multiply sequence by non-int of type ‘float’
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error :(

Comment: you can try loading to df from csv file with those values, then you will get error while multiplying

Comment: @Peter what is the output of `df.dtypes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're getting this issue because of type. you can try to convert the column to float type -

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'years':['Y0','Y1','Y2','Y3'],'price1':[0.01, 0.0029,0.00368,0.00439536], 'price2':[0.02, 0.001, 9.161781253394068e-04,0.001718]})

# converting dtype
df['price1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price1'], errors='coerce')
df['price2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price2'], errors='coerce')
df.iloc[1:,1:] = df.iloc[1:,1:].mul(0.75)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as below?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"years":["Y0","Y1","Y2","Y3"],
                 "price1":[0.01, 0.0029,0.00368,0.00439536], 
                 "price2":[0.02, 0.001, float("9.161781253394068e-04"),0.001718]})

df.iloc[1:,1:] = df.iloc[1:,1:].mul(0.75)
```

Comment: Thank you berkayln, that scientific notation values can be present anywhere in df. So is there a way to convert entire dataframe to float except first row and column

Comment: yes: df.astype({'price1': 'float64',"price2":"float64"})

Comment: but this will still convert the first row in price1, price 2 to float but I don’t want them to float, as they used with specific format in my app, so any easy way of doing this

Comment: 0.01 is already float men:D I really could not understand.